# Simplifying $\tan^{-1} {\cot(\frac{-1}4)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

> Simplify $\tan^{-1} {\cot(\frac{-1}4)}$

I have been trying to solve this and I end up with 4, while the correct answer is $(\frac{1}4 - \frac{\pi}{2})$. Please help

Comment: $\tan^{-1}x$ takes values between $\pm\pi/2$: $4$ is well outside that interval.

Comment: Does $\tan(\frac14-\frac\pi2)=\cot(-\frac14)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\cot \left(-\frac14\right)=-\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac14\right)=\tan\left(\frac14-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

thus

$$\tan^{-1}\cot \left(-\frac14\right)=\tan^{-1}\tan\left(\frac14-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac14-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Oh, I have been so blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $\tan({\pi \over 2} - x) ={ \sin({\pi \over 2} - x) \over \cos({\pi \over 2} - x) } = {\cos(x) \over \sin(x)} = {1\over\tan(x)}$